# Keras model ValueError python

Tags: python, keras, valueerror

I'm new to Keras and I'm getting a ValueError in the following code:

```
    self.policy = DQN(self.batch_size) # DQN is a class extending keras.Model
    self.policy.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy")
    self.policy.build(input_shape=(self.batch_size, 19, 19, 3))
    tf.keras.models.Model.summary(self.policy)
    self.target = tf.keras.models.clone_model(self.policy) # <---- ERROR
```

Error message:
ValueError: Expected `model` argument to be a functional `Model` instance, but got a subclass model instead.

I'm not sure why this is happening, maybe I forgot to call some initialization method?

Comment: Only Sequential or Functional models can be cloned, not subclass models.

Comment: Thanks, that did it